# How do I programmatically use Photoshop Neural Filter using python / node js?

Tags: python, node.js, deep-learning, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm Kevin a Junior Software Developer

I have tried searching for a lot of resources to programmatically use Photoshop:

1. Trying Photoshop Python API https://github.com/loonghao/photoshop-python-api
2. Trying COM (Component Object Model) API from Windows to control photoshop app
3. Learning about Photoshop API https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/api/ , (this is the worst because I need to use my own PC, not Adobe's owned PC)

However, none of them covers the API of using Neural Filter, which is available on Photoshop 2021 and 2022

My use-case is to automate some task: de-aging people photos (make old person look younger).
and applying some landscape filter.

I fairly know python and node js and able to program with it.

May someone help me solve my problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't do that yet.

Because current core **Photoshop Object Model 2020** which allows you to access Photoshop components hasn't been supported Neural Filter.

Take a look at Photoshop Object Model here [photoshop-scripting-guide-2020.pdf](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/Documentation/Product%20specific%20Documentation/Photoshop%20Scripting/photoshop-scripting-guide-2020.pdf). They locked Copy and Edit in their docs file, you may use this instead [docs-unlocked](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/scripting-guide-copy-blocked/m-p/12132508#:%7E:text=Advocacy%20%2D%20Digital%20Imaging-,photoshop%2Dscripting%2Dguide%2D2020_unlocked.pdf,Preview,-Likes).